# Pass data between chrome extension and webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dispatch

I'm trying to create tiny chrome extension.

This one has one input that contains login that user can typea dn a button. Once clicked, script is injected to current page and I'm trying to pass data (the login entered in extension html) but it looks it isn't running and I don't know how to test it more in order to find the reason why it isn't running.

At this point, the alert("inject is running"); is runing but not the alert("csEvent fired"); when I press the button and ther eis no error message in the extension manager.

Here is the code:

Manifest

```
{
"name" :"Quick Pass",
"version" :"1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description" :"Password for quick access",
"browser_action" :
    {
        "default_icon" : "icone.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": ["inject.js"],
    "permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

buttonScript.js

```
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

// When user clicks on the submit button of the extension, load the script on current tab
function myFunction() {
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){
      chrome.tabs.executeScript({
          file: 'inject.js'
        });
    });

    // data you want to sent
    let data = {
        login: document.getElementById("loginPopup").value,
        pwd: "Password"
    };
    // send data through a DOM event
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('csEvent', {detail: data}));

}
```

inject.js

```
// Injected from Chrome "APPI Pass" extension

(function() {

alert("inject is running");

document.addEventListener('csEvent', function (event) {

    alert("csEvent fired");
    console.log(event.detail.login+event.detail.pwd);

    document.getElementById("Email").value = event.detail.login;
    document.getElementById("Password").value = event.detail.pwd
    document.getElementByTagName("form").submit();
});

})();
```

And the popup.html:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Appi Magic</h2>
<h3>Enter Login:</h3>
<input type="text" id="loginPopup">
<button id="myButton">Let go</button>

<script src="buttonScript.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Right now, you are dispatching your custom event in the same popup window. In order to communicate with the content script, you have to use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging), especifically [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) in your popup script and [`chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) in your content script.

Comment: Hey @IvanNokonoko thank you for your help. I've checked all you gave and especialli found https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging very usefull. You can make a reply with it and I will set it as right response ;-) Have a nice day and thanks again